# Операции с boolean в Java

Tags: java

Не могу правильно понять манипуляцию с булевым значением в цикле for .

```
  boolean boo = false;
    for (int i = 0; !boo && (i < 3); ++i) {
        try (//code...);
            boo = true;
        }
```

Условие в цикле я читаю так: если `boo` НЕ `false` и `i` меньше `3`, то делай так-то. То есть условие в цикле `for` должно выполнится, когда `boo` будет равен `true`.Но вопреки всему код работает и потому в голове образовалась каша. Помогите, пож-а, правильно "перевести" на русский язык этот код.

Comment: наоборот, условие в цикле for должно выполнится, когда boo будет **не** равен true, а вот пока оно false - все работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изначально boo = **false**

!boo = !**false** = true

Получается наоборот, что условие должно выполняться, когда boo = **false**

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; boo && (i < 3); ++i) { // Начнётся если boo== true и i<3  
 try (//code...);
   if(условие){ boo = false} // при выполнении определённого условия ставим boo=false и выходим из цикла
 }
```